# Not able to enable CORS for identity server 4 in asp.net core

Tags: c#, cors, .net-core, identityserver4

Ok, I have added CORS policy for my dot net core APIs but somehow these CORS policies are not working for identity server 4 endpoints. 
I have following api where I try to register a user:

```
    [EnableCors("AllowAllCorsPolicy")]
    [Route("api/User")]
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private IUserServices _userService;
        public UserController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IUserServices userService)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _userService = userService;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<int> Post([FromBody]User userInfo)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser{  UserName = userInfo.Name, Email = userInfo.Email,
                UserTypeId = Constant.User, CustomerId = userInfo.CustomerId };

            //Follwing 3 lines give CORS issue.
            await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, Constant.User);
            var userClaim = new Claim(Constant.User, user.Email.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer);
            await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, userClaim);

            // var userObj = _userService.AddNewUser(userInfo);
        }
```

Now if I use above identity server methods (**AddToRoleAsync()** and **AddClaimAsync()**) I get CORS error in my client (angular app running on different server)

However if I use my custom method to register the user, I don't get CORS error:

```
            //Don't get CORS error when commented below
            //await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, Constant.User);
            //var userClaim = new Claim(Constant.User, user.Email.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer);
            //await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, userClaim);

            //use custom method
            var userObj = _userService.AddNewUser(userInfo);
```

To enable CORS for asp.net, startup.cs I am doing:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
              services.AddCors(options =>
             {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAllCorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowCredentials());
            });
            services.AddMvc();
          }


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,  IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            app.UseCors("AllowAllCorsPolicy");
        }
```

I even tried to add the CORS headers manually in startup.cs, but no luck:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,  IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if (context.Request.Method == "OPTIONS")
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;

            var headers = context.Response.Headers;
            if (headers.ContainsKey("Access-Control-Allow-Origin"))
            {
                headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = string.Join(",", context.Request.Headers["Referer"].Select(x => x.Substring(0, x.Length - 1)));
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", string.Join(",", context.Request.Headers["Referer"].Select(x => x.Substring(0, x.Length - 1))));
            }
            if (headers.ContainsKey("Access-Control-Allow-Headers"))
            {
                headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Client, Authorization, X-Auth-Token, X-Requested-With";
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Client, Authorization, X-Auth-Token, X-Requested-With");
            }
            if (headers.ContainsKey("Access-Control-Allow-Methods"))
            {
                headers["Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"] = "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS";
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
            }
            if (headers.ContainsKey("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"))
            {
                headers["Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"] = "true";
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            }
            context.Response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "X-Auth-Token");
            context.Response.Headers.Append("Vary", "Origin");
            await next();
        });
        }
```

I saw [this documentation](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/reference/options.html#cors) for identityserver Options for CORS and also [this CORS](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/cors.html?highlight=Configure%20Services) documentation but not much helpful.

Comment: Why are you not using `app.UseIdentityServer` and `services.AddIdentityServer`?

Comment: is your identityserver client properly defined?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works for the newer version of the server.

```
    services.AddSingleton<ICorsPolicyService>((container) => {
        var logger = container.GetRequiredService<ILogger<DefaultCorsPolicyService>>();
        return new DefaultCorsPolicyService(logger)
        {
            AllowAll = true
        };
    });
```

more details here at this discussion, with credit to the original author

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/4685

Comment: I had the issue, but weirdly only on mobile (tested with brave and ff).. This has been the fix for me!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using IdentityServer 4 with clients for authentication you must configure CORS with IdentityServer 4 see : [IdentityServer4CORS](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/cors.html)

IdentityServer4 CORS is for the token endpoint only.
What you did is configure the CORS for all the controller/methods which is probably correct in your case. However, you won't be able to retrieve the token if you don't enable CORS on identityserver4.

You can either add a list of allowed CORS to your clients that will be added to the identityserver database OR add a global default one like this :

```
var cors = new DefaultCorsPolicyService(_loggerFactory.CreateLogger<DefaultCorsPolicyService>())
{
    AllowedOrigins = { "https://foo", "https://bar" }
};
services.AddSingleton<ICorsPolicyService>(cors);
```

Note that you can manually add it to the database too.

Comment: Ok, how do this in .net core 3.0? _loggerFactory.CreateLogger not supported anymore

Comment: @ТарасКрасниця It's seem supported : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: I mean u can't add ILoggerFactory in method  ConfigureServices in core 3.0
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)

In ASP.NET Core 3.0 and later, it is no longer possible to inject ILogger in Startup.cs and Program.cs. See [link](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/353) for more details.

I already found a solution

services.AddSingleton<ICorsPolicyService, CustomCorsPolicyService>();

Comment: @ТарасКрасниця, can you please unpack a bit more on your solution to this. I get the AddSingleton piece, but how did you implement CustomCorsPolicyService? Thanks.

Comment: @ТарасКрасниця The Ilogger should be injected in the StartUp constructor like so ->  public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger). Create a variable and you will be able to access it