# IdentityServer4 CORS

Tags: c#, node.js, vue.js, axios, identityserver4

I have an node.js application with vue.js using axios to make Http calls. I am trying to authenticate through a new IdentityServer4. My clientserver make the call usign axios:

```
axios.post(`${API_AUTH}/connect/token`, form)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data)
      resolve(response.data)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      reject(err)
    })
```

On Startup class of my IdentityServer

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
        });

        var cors = new DefaultCorsPolicyService(_logger)
        {
            AllowAll = true
        };

        services.AddSingleton<ICorsPolicyService>(cors);

        services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.InputLengthRestrictions.Password = 255;
        })
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
            .Services.AddTransient<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();
    }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

        app.UseIdentityServer();
    }
```

And also I tried to configure my clients like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    {
        return new List<Client>
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "ClientId ",
                ClientName = "ClientName ",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
                AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("123423412341243214".Sha256())
                },
                AllowedCorsOrigins = { "http://127.0.0.1:8080", "http://localhost:8080" },
                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    IdentityServerConstants.ClaimValueTypes.Json,
                    "Abc",
                    "Abcd"
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

But when I try to call http://localhost:5000/connect/token I receive: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

Comment: Try to move `services.AddCors...` after `services.AddIdentityServer....` and remove the `DefaultCorsPolicyService` stuff (both creating the object, and adding the singleton).

Comment: I tried but the error remains the same. Is there any way to test the server's response? Because I'm being blocked directly in the browser. The request does not even arrive on the server.

Comment: OK another option (this is how I've implemented it) - `services.AddIdentityServer()` has `.AddCorsPolicyService<ICorsPolicyService>` option. Implement the interface according to your needs and try like that. Remove all the other cors related stuff in the `startup.cs`.

Comment: have updated an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43343672/not-able-to-enable-cors-for-identity-server-4-in-asp-net-core/63136404