# identity server multiple issues after deployment

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

My current setup is like this. The entire project was built using the official docs here - https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

1. API Server
2. Auth Server with local login, google login and github login
3. Console based c# client
4. JS based client
5. MVC based client.

(all of it, as described in the official docs)

Locally, all of them work beautifully. Able to login, access api endpoints, logout, redirect, the whole thing works smooth.

I have deployed all 5 of them to five different azure web apps. They all have the standard xyz.azurewebsites.net domains ready to use. Now, I have run into some problems.
the console C# client is able to talk to the deployed auth server, collect token using a local account on the auth server and make calls to the deployed API server. Based on this, I assume that both the api server and the auth server working hand in hand, as they should.

Problem #1 - the JS client keeps saying

```
'The login is blocked because of CORS Missing Allow Origin '
```

Problem #2 - the MVC client loads the auth server, and then the auth server gives me this error.

```
Sorry, there was an error : unauthorized_client
Request Id: 80005c0f-0000-eb00-b63f-84710c7967bb
```

Note : I have set the CORS policy on the auth server, both these clients, under client definition as follows. I am not too concerned about keeping the auth server open, so dont mind if any and every domain can call the auth server.

```
AllowedCorsOrigins =     { "*.*" },
```

Also Note : I have set the URLS in the code before deployment. all loclahost:port number lines have been replaced correctly with the corresponding now published URLs.

So, what am I missing out here?

**Update 1**

I was able to solve the CORS issue. Have posted a answer here on another question.

[Not able to enable CORS for identity server 4 in asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43343672/not-able-to-enable-cors-for-identity-server-4-in-asp-net-core/63136404)

**Update 2**

So, now, both the JS client and the MVC client, are giving identical errors.

Sorry, there was an error : unauthorized_client
Request Id: 80005c0f-0000-eb00-b63f-84710c7967bb

**Update 3**

I have opened an issue which has log details.

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/4691

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this counts as an answer, but posting for my own question, as it might might help others. Also, this is only a guess at this point.

I found out that the redirects were permanently stored in the database I used with EF migrations. That mean, local in memory redirects were being overwritten anyway by the database stored migrations. I believe this is the issue.

I also realized that the console app is working fine for it does not depend on redirect URLs where as the JS and MVC based clients dont work because they do depend on redirect URLs.

At this point, the best thing to do and for you (if you used EF migrations to store your auth server configuration) on database would be start over and switch to in memory only. Alternatively, you can try and update the database to suit your deployment requirements.

Ultimately, I believe, unless it is absolutely necessary, keep the auth server config (like redirects and CORS settings) in memory as they dont take up much value and are rarely changed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, instead of having Identity Server collect the URI from database, I instead added the redirect URI into the application using Identity Server. So inside of my `.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options => SetOpenIdConnectOptions(options));` call, I modified my `OnRedirectToIdentityProvider`
to this:

```
OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = n => {
            if(n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Logout) {
                var idTokenHint = n.HttpContext.User.FindFirst("id_token");

                if(idTokenHint != null)
                    n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint.Value;
            } else {
                n.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = AppSettings.postAuthReturnUrl; //THIS LINE!
            }

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
```